# Angular with Oauth2: Change Password User Flow

Tags: php, angular, oauth-2.0, oauth

In Angular, how can I implement OAuth2 / OpenID Connect to change passwords?

In Angular, I use this library: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc

On the backend side, I have successfully logged in via AuthorizationServer which I built myself using PHP using https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php.

[image: AuthServer in PHP]

The grant type used is Authorization Code Flow with PKCE. As a result, Angular successfully obtained the access_token and refresh_token, so it can be considered a successful login.

[image]

The results you want to achieve:

- User clicks the change password link in Angular,
- Angular redirect to AuthServer
- Successfully changed the password, AuthServer again directs (a kind of callback) to Angular.

How can I implement this change-password?

Comment: What is the relation between OAuth2 and changing password? One is to validate the private server resources, the other is just a database record.

Comment: Ok, I know. I mean, I want to implement change password like authorization code flow in OAuth2, where user is redirect to AuthServer for authenticate.